# Adding IP allocation with ifcfg gives wrong broadcast address?

Tags: centos, ip, ifconfig, subnets

I got a /29 IP allocation from my ISP.

I added them using ifcfg to the range file for my interface: ifcfg-eth0-range:0

(NOTE: I replaced my actual IPs with private IPs here.)

```
IPADDR_START=192.168.2.0
IPADDR_END=192.168.2.7
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
```

The IPs in these range show 192.168.2.0 as broadcast address when using ip or ifconfig, but this can't be right?
Broadcast address would be 192.168.2.7 if I added them using netmask=255.255.255.248.
I checked whether I could reach my host using IP 192.168.2.0 and it works fine.

So this makes me believe it's not really the broadcast address for this IP range.

Have I configured this correctly?

My main IP is 192.168.1.25
Netmask=255.255.255.224
Gateway=192.168.1.1
Broadcast=192.168.1.31

I thought about setting 192.168.1.31 as broadcast address for these additional IPs, but I was told the broadcast address needs to be in the same subnet.
Also manually setting the broadcast in ifcfg is deprecated.

What should I do?

EDIT: Added output of `ip a` and `ip r`

```
 #ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.25/27 brd 192.168.1.31 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.0/29 brd 192.168.2.0 scope global eth0:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.1/29 brd 192.168.2.0 scope global secondary eth0:2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.2/29 brd 192.168.2.0 scope global secondary eth0:3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.3/29 brd 192.168.2.0 scope global secondary eth0:4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.4/29 brd 192.168.2.0 scope global secondary eth0:5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.5/29 brd 192.168.2.0 scope global secondary eth0:6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.6/29 brd 192.168.2.0 scope global secondary eth0:7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.7/29 brd 192.168.2.0 scope global secondary eth0:8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fea6:127e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 #ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/27 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.25
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002
192.168.2.0/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.0
```

Comment: How is `192.168.2.0/29` related to `192.168.1.0/27`? You mention both without explanation. Are they configured on and routed to the same interface (or IP, respectively)?

Comment: @HaukeLaging They are both configured on the same interface (eth0) in this case yes. IPs 192.168.1.25 and 192.168.2.0 -192.168.2.7 belong to the same host here.

Comment: Add the outputs of `ip a` and `ip r` to your question. Is `192.168.1.0/27` a public subnet? And see the **subnet routing** block I added to my answer.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I've added the outputs, and yes 192.168.1.0/27 and 192.168.2.0/29 in this case are public subnets.

Comment: So you do not want to route the new subnet to other systems, the host shall respond to all those addresses itself? Can you reach the `192.168.2.0/29` addresses from the Internet now?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I can reach the addresses from the internet including 192.168.2.0 which here shows as broadcast. But the broadcast address shouldn't be reachable if I'm correct.

I want to know why 192.168.2.0 shows as broadcast address. I did the same configuration with netmask 255.255.255.248 and here 192.168.2.7 is the broadcast address which is correct.

Also some further clarification: the ISP said I can use all 8 IPs from this /29 allocation.
Normally in such an allocation there are 6 usable IPs, 1 network address and 1 broadcast address.

They recommended 255.255.255.255 as netmask.

Comment: For the time being I added option `BROADCAST=0` to my ifcfg file. Now `ip a` shows there is no broadcast address for the IP range I've just added which seems to be correct.
This option is deprecated though so it's a hack, but I guess this works until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The subnet `192.168.2.0` to `192.168.2.7` is `192.168.2.0/29` i.e. the netmask is `255.255.255.248`, not `255.255.255.255`. In `192.168.2.0/29` `192.168.2.0` is the network address i.e. not a valid host address.

### subnet routing

You have to find out whether your ISP is routing `192.168.2.0/29` to an IP outside that range (e.g. `192.168.1.25`) or whether the uplink IP is within that network. If the subnet is routed then you do not need any IP from it on that interface.

Comment: So I should assign these IPs as /29 and not /32?

Comment: Uplink IP here is 192.168.1.25.

Comment: @mrmc `ip a` and `ip r` show that `192.168.1.1` is the uplink.

Comment: Understood. Yes that's the gateway for my host.